# angular 4 after set useHash to true got an exception

Tags: jquery, angular

I have set the var useHash to true and got the following exception as soon as the page is loaded.

```
zone.js:195 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/
at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at new r.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at r (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.bundle.js:7)
at jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
at Function.map (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

The changed code was:

```
 export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

After shift to jquery-3.2.1.js:

ON Zone.js:

```
try {
            if (task.type == macroTask && task.data && 
!task.data.isPeriodic) {
                task.cancelFn = null;
            }
            try {
                return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, 
applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }
```

On jquery-3.2.1.js

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
  throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg ); 
 };
```

My app.routing.ts looks like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: EntryComponent },
    { path: 'entry', component: EntryComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: 
[GuardService] },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', component: AppComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Any clue how to fix this ?

Comment: can you add more information to help you

Comment: You will get better stack trace information if you **use  `jquery.js`** instead of `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Can you as @Aravind said add more information ? Maybe it has to deal with the way you made routing inside your html files.

Comment: I added the content of app.routing.ts

Comment: did you change the `base` tag in your html?

Comment: The index.html basically contains :  <app-root>  </app-root> then the main component html contains:  <router-outlet></router-outlet> and a navbar from bootstrap. what do you mean the base tag ? Thanks

Comment: My base url form index.html on head is <base href="/">